# IE8 crashed tab recovery log?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

We run a realtime discussion type website which has quite a bit of JS code to manage the chatting. We are still in development so the code is not 100% solid but it runs OK.

We are finding that the chat stream very occassionally causes IE8 to crash a tab and do a recovery. No worries in other browsers.

It's very intermittent and it's difficult to know where to start except ripping bits of code and waiting for a week or so to see if it still happens. Which is a pain.

Basically, does anyone know of any IE8 debugging feature that will let us know what's up *after* the crash/recovery ?

Comment: Could it be a memory leak? Have you checked memory usage for the IE process over time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything offhand.  My only suggestion would be to do some logging of your own... and hopefully you can trace where things were going just before it crashed and thus determine what caused it.

e.g. using AJAX

```
log('doing this');
foo.doThis(bar);
log('doing that');
foo.doThat(baz);
log('doing the other');
foo.doTheOther(boz);
```

where `log()` makes an AJAX call to your server, logging some data to a file.

After a crash, inspect the logs to determine where things got to before failing:

```
2010-04-06 12:37:14:138 doing this
2010-04-06 12:37:14:462 doing that
{crash}
```

Comment: Or monitoring the traffic using Fiddler might show a pattern to the crashes as well.